# Tesseract C++: specify the AMOUNT of characters to find

Tags: c++, tesseract

I am using Tesseract 3.05 in a c++ project via cmd call using `system()`. I want to specify in advance the number of characters to be classified by Tesseract.

For instance, as an input, I have a line of text with **exactly 10 characters** in it. 
Tesseract often output results with **!= 10** characters due to misclassification.

Is there a possibility in the vastness of the Tesseract parameters to cope with this?

What about the `permute_fixed_length_dawg` parameter?

I am already making use of the `tessedit_char_blacklist` and `tessedit_char_whitelist` parameter.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Changing `permute_fixed_length_dawg` (your word is probably not in the dawg anyway) or specifying custom dawg would likely not change anything & in the best scenario would only affect the confidence of the result data. Parameters which you should look at are the ones that affect spaces inbetween words. You should also preprocess your image better so that it is clearer for tesseract.

Comment: Thanks. I did more processing regarding spaces and could isolate connected parts (i. e. segmenting between every single space as well as linebreaks). I was also able to segment the single characters with pretty well (no overlapping). When I applied Tesseract `--psm 10` on single characters, the results was much worse than on entire text segments (with `psm --7`) (although these are often no actual englisch words) - why cant I receive similiar results?

Comment: As you mention the confidence - is it possible to output the confidence for instance for the single character recogntion?

Comment: I don't think you can get a confidence with CLI (you can try tsv, but as far as i remember it only gives you word level confidence), but you can do it easily with c++ API by getting iterator and setting iterate level to `tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL`

Comment: Regarding `psm 10` and `7` - it is impossible to say without seeing your input.

Comment: I will try setting the iterate level to `tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL`. I am using `psm 10` for single lines, i. e. no spaces, no linebreak, arbitrary characters, e. g. "MFG19284H67UIHB". I am using `psm 7` on single segmented characters, image binarized. So just a black ''7" on white background.